# How can external UITableView delegate hide the UISearchBar keyboard?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a table view with a data source/delegate in another file. In addition, there is a search bar above the table view that belongs to the first file. In other to hide the keyboard when scrolling, I would need to call:

```
[self.searchBar resignFirstResponder]
```

But the

```
(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

method is in the delegate. So how would I hide the keyboard when scrolling in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could send a notification in scrollviewwillbegindragging. tableview delegate:

```
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"resign" object:nil];
}
```

searchbar delegate:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
     [super viewDidLoad];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(goTo:) name:@"resign" object:nil];
}

-(void)goTo:(NSNotification*)notification {
[self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do,a couple of them are below.

option 1:
add below line after initializing your table object

```
[yourTableView setKeyboardDismissMode:UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag];
```

or

option 2:
Get your tableview's superview(i'm expecting that as aViewcontrollerObj.view) and forcibly end its editing .

```
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    UIView *tableviewSuperView = yourTableView.superview;
    [tableviewSuperView endEditing:true];
}
```

Hope that helps 
Happy coding :)